# Can I avoid putting return 0 by changing the function type from int to void?

Tags: c

int main()
{
...
return 0;
}

void main()
{
...
}

I put printf("Hello") in both cases and I got the same result. The void version took longer to compile though.. I was wondering what's the difference and does it make any difference if I go with int main and then put return or just put void main to avoid putting return.

Comment: `void main` is not mandated by the C standard, so it may or may not be supported by a compiler. However `return 0;` is not required in `main` (since C99)

Comment: `return 0` means here when program is executed successfully it exit with status code `0`.  it a good habit to define return code

Comment: Please, please, please: Always declare `main` as `int`.  Never declare it as `void`.  Now, declaring it as `void` won't actually cause you too many problems, it's true, but strictly speaking it's *wrong*, and at the very least, you'll have to keep arguing and defending it, while no one can object to `int`.  Also `int` is one less character to type than `void`!

Comment: You don't actually even need the `return 0;` any more — the compiler will do it for you automatically — but it obviously doesn't hurt to put it there, and it's not *that* much typing.  (For any real program, those nine characters "`return 0;`" will obviously be a tiny percentage of the total, and therefore aren't a significant cost.)

Answer (score 1):

Take an example of below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        printf("hello world\n");
        return 0;
}
```

compile and run above code

```
$ gcc -Wall test.c
$ ./a.out
hello world
 to get exit status run `$?` it will return 0
$ echo $?
0
```

Now change return to some other integer like 1

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        printf("hello world\n");
        return 1;
}
```

Compile and execute

```
$ gcc -Wall test.c
$ ./a.out
hello world
$ echo $?
1               # it returned exit status as 1
```

Lets try with main only and no return:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main() {
        printf("hello world\n");
        
}
```

Compiler warns and use the default type int

```
$ gcc -Wall test.c
test.c:3:2: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
    3 |  main() {
      |  ^~~~
$ ./a.out
hello world
$ echo $?
0               # exit status 0
```

Now lets try with void main and no return

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
        printf("hello world\n");
        
}
```

compiler warns about return type of main is not int

```
$ gcc -Wall test.c
test.c:3:6: warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’ [-Wmain]
    3 | void main() {
      |      ^~~~
$ ./a.out
hello world
$ echo $?
12
```

Its a good practice to include exit code in your program to know is your program is executed successfully